# Javascript event handlers overwriting?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to add rulers to a google map and have those available.

It's all working well, but the "Delete Ruler" event handler seems to not work right. (See function "addLine")

```
// Set up the event handler for the remove ruler button
document.getElementById('delruler' + num).onclick = function() {removeLine(num); return false;}
```

What ends up happening is that I can delete the last ruler I've added, but not any of the ones before it. I can go into the console and type `removeLine(3)` and remove the #3 line, so I'm fairly sure that the rest of it is working... It's just the event handlers that are getting overwritten or something?

This should be setting up event handlers for divs called "delruler1", "delruler2", etc... What have I gotten wrong? Full code is below. Thank you for your help.

```
var lines = new Array();

function addruler() {
var ruler1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter() ,
    map: map,
    draggable: true
});
var ruler2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter() ,
    map: map,
    draggable: true
});
var ruler1label = new Label({ map: map });
var ruler2label = new Label({ map: map });
ruler1label.bindTo('position', ruler1, 'position');
ruler2label.bindTo('position', ruler2, 'position');
var rulerpoly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [ruler1.position, ruler2.position] ,
    strokeColor: "#0098b5",
    strokeOpacity: .7,
    strokeWeight: 7
});
rulerpoly.setMap(map);
ruler1label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
ruler2label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
google.maps.event.addListener(ruler1, 'drag', function() {
    rulerpoly.setPath([ruler1.getPosition(), ruler2.getPosition()]);
    ruler1label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
    ruler2label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
});
google.maps.event.addListener(ruler2, 'drag', function() {
    rulerpoly.setPath([ruler1.getPosition(), ruler2.getPosition()]);
    ruler1label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
    ruler2label.set('text',distance( ruler1.getPosition().lat(), ruler1.getPosition().lng(), ruler2.getPosition().lat(), ruler2.getPosition().lng()));
});
// Add our new ruler to an array for later reference
lines.push([ruler1, ruler2, ruler1label, ruler2label, rulerpoly]);
addLine(lines.length - 1);
}

function addLine (num) {
// This function adds a line to our page.
var div = document.getElementById('latlon');
var oldHTML = document.getElementById('latlon').innerHTML;
div.innerHTML = oldHTML + "<div id='ruler" + num + "'><span id='latlon_dir'><input type='text' name='dir' id='dir' length='2' /></span><span id='latlon_street'><input type='text' name='street' id='street' length='30' /></span><span id='latlon_traffic'><input type='text' name='traffic' id='traffic' length='6' /></span><span id='latlon_speed'><input type='text' name='speed' id='speed' length='2' /></span><span id='latlon_stop'><select name='stop' id='stop'><option value='Y'>Yes</option><option value='N'>No</option></select> </span><span id='latlon_viewdistance'><input type='text' name='viewingdistance' id='viewingdistance' length='10' /></span><span><button type='button' class='delruler' id='delruler" + num + "' >Delete Ruler</button></span><br>";
// Set up the event handler for the remove ruler button
document.getElementById('delruler' + num).onclick = function() {removeLine(num); return;}
}

function removeLine (num) {
// Removes the line from our HTML page
var div = document.getElementById('ruler' + num);
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
removeRuler(lines[num]);
}

function removeRuler (r) {
// Now we remove the ruler.
// I've unpacked the variables for readability.
var ruler1=r[0]; var ruler2=r[1]; var ruler1label=r[2]; var ruler2label=r[3]; var rulerpoly=r[4];
google.maps.event.clearListeners(ruler1, 'drag');
ruler1.setMap(null);
google.maps.event.clearListeners(ruler2, 'drag');
ruler2.setMap(null);
ruler1label.setMap(null);
ruler2label.setMap(null);
rulerpoly.setMap(null);
}

function distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
var R = 3959; // Here's the right settings for miles and feet
var dLat = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
var dLon = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI / 180; 
var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180 ) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c;
if (d>1) return Math.round(d)+"mi";
else if (d<=1) return Math.round(d*5280)+"ft";
return d;
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to read through full source code. Could you find a smaller code sample? Maybe in doing so you will find your answer

Answer (score 0):

Javascript **will** overwrite event handlers, `document.getElementById(...)` returns an object with a few variables in it. You can prove this by running the following code in your browser's developer console:

```
$.each(document.getElementById("comments-link-16801451"), function(key, data) { console.log(key + ' - ' + data); });
```

On this page that returns this:
[image]

Now back to your question, the `onclick` property from the object that `getElementById` returns is simply a variable with an anonymous function as it's value. That can be proven by running this in your developer console:

```
document.getElementById("comments-link-16801451").onclick = function() { console.log("test"); };
document.getElementById("comments-link-16801451").onclick();
```

[image]

**EDIT:** I read your question wrong. In your `removeLine` function, `document.getElementById('ruler' + num);` should be `document.getElementById('delruler' + num);` I'll just leave all that up there for future reference for anybody that stumbles across here.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer, and finding my typo as well. The first part was very educational, and actually will help me quite a bit as well so I know how to debug something of this nature in the future. Again, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Actually, the outer div that surrounds the line of input boxes is "ruler1", "ruler2", etc... So that is correct for it to want to select ruler1. delruler is the name of the button.